# C# Dice game, turn this into a user typed input

Tags: c#, random, int, dice

Ive made a dice "game" which randomly chooses a number and then "rolls" to see how many rolls it takes to get the same number. The problem im having is how can I make the `pyöräytys` to be  typed in by the user.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Noppapeli
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int pyöräytys;
            int satunnainen;
            int luku = 0;

            Random noppa = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out pyöräytys);
            Console.WriteLine("Arvon numeron ja sitten koitan saada sen uudelleen");
            Console.WriteLine("Haettava numero on: " + pyöräytys);
            Console.ReadLine();
            do
            {
                luku++;
                satunnainen = noppa.Next(1, 7);
                Console.WriteLine("numero on: " + satunnainen);
                if (satunnainen == pyöräytys)
                {
                    satunnainen = pyöräytys;
                }
            } while (pyöräytys != satunnainen);

            Console.WriteLine("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^");
            Console.WriteLine("Haettu numero: " + pyöräytys);
            Console.WriteLine("Pyöräytetty numero: " + satunnainen);
            Console.Write("Kesti " + luku + " Nopan pyöräytystä saada tulos!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried changing the `pyöräytys = noppa.Next(1,7);` to something that would read the key that is pressed but couldnt find anything.

EDIT:
Thanks for the solution WhileTrueSleep, i updated it in the code above. Just another thing, now that I can input a number over 6 it goes on a infinite loop. how would I make it so that the number must be between 1-6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out pyöräytys);
```

Edit: Replace this line against  `pyöräytys = noppa.Next(1, 7);`
The user now can enter the value in the console. If the input is not valid then `pyöräytys` will stay by its default value (0).

Comment: Because it said `knäckebröd = Console.ReadLine()`, which cannot be done as the former was defined as `int`. Now it is corrected, but still not a good answer as it contains no explanation.

Comment: Im trying to use this but im not 100% certain am i doing it right seen as i cant get it to work.EDIT I did that but it gives me the error 'System.Console' does not contain a definition for 'ReadLine'

Comment: @Fruktoosi i corrected it. it has to be ReadLine of course not Readline

Comment: I noticed it my self but even with correct typing it gives me the error i stated above

Comment: @CodeCaster - knäckebröd... thanks for making my day brighter! ^_^

Comment: Got it. Me and my bad eyes, i totally missed the out!

Answer (score -2):

`Console.ReadLine()` returns a string, which you can [try to parse into an int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx), which you can then use in a [for loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx).